# Syntax for connecting models to admin, Django

Tags: python, django

I have been learning python for some months, and started tinkering with Django. Before posting this, I read up on the auto-generated 'admin.py'-code on github, as well as googled the matter. It appears my question is a little specific, and I was quite frankly very confused from that specific reading. Thus, I hope asking this adds value to this wonderful community. Question:

When connecting a model to the admin page, in admin.py, you first import admin:

> from django.contrib import admin

After this, you import your model. Then, you supposedly connect your model through:

> admin.site.register(MODEL)

What I do not understand is what 'site.register' is. The fact that the line starts off with 'admin.' makes perfect sense, as you are specifying from where the following import (ex. 'admin.function' or 'admin.class') comes from. Had it only been 'admin.somefunctionfromadmin' I would have totally understood this. Now, instead, I am confused as to what 'sites.register' is. 
Is 'sites' a module, a file, and 'register' a function from within that module? If so, what does that make 'admin'? A package?

I have seen lines similar to these throughout Django, and feel a bit confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin.site` is the default instance of the [`AdminSite`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcd431c6c3159a753f1cc0658cc4b25803ffccc1/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L29) class. It is [instantiated](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcd431c6c3159a753f1cc0658cc4b25803ffccc1/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L523) in `django.contrib.admin.sites`.

It is then [imported](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcd431c6c3159a753f1cc0658cc4b25803ffccc1/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py#L13) in the `django/contrib/admin/__init__.py`. This makes it available as `admin.site` when you have done `from django.contrib import admin`.

When you call `admin.site.register(Model)`, you are calling the `register` method of this admin site instance.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. To clarify: site is an instance of the AdminSite class, instantiated within sites.py. Admin.py inherits from sites.py, thus making it possible to import it in the __init__ method of django.contrib.admin. Then, in admin.site.register(Model), register is a method from within the site-instance (of the AdminSite class), and I pass my model name as an argument. Would this be a correct understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure about your description *Admin.py inherits from sites.py thus making it possible*. Note that you're not passing a model name (e.g. `"MyModel"`) when you call `admin.site.register()`, you are passing the actual model class. Apart from that, I think you've got it.

Comment: Alright, I now understand. Admin is not a file, but rather a directory. Regarding the __init__.py file, am I right to understand it as this: without it, Admin will not be regarded as a package, and it will be impossible to import from, for example sites. Moreover, __init__ allows me to import functions and classes etc, thus making them easier to import in a script (making it possible to go 'admin.site' instead of 'admin.sites.site'). IF this is true, I think I've completely got it! Thank you S O much! Really. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Yes, the `__init__.py` is used to simplify imports. Note that [as of Python 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), the `__init__.py` is not necessary to make it a package.